# Why are tan, acos and asin methods missing from Ruby's BigMath module?

Tags: ruby, bigdecimal

I noticed that the [BigMath module](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigMath.html) from Ruby standard library contains several methods to do trigonometry with `BigDecimal` numbers, such as `BigMath.cos`.

However, tangent (`tan`), arccosine (`acos`) and arcsine (`asin`) methods are not implemented in the module. They are available from the `Math` module, which deals with `Float` numbers, but not `BigDecimal`.

I am wondering what prevented from implementing them in the first place, and what it would take to implement them now.

Thank you.

Comment: There's [an open ticket](https://github.com/ruby/bigdecimal/issues/81) for `tan` and it has been there for almost 5 years with no solution, so I suppose lack of someone implementing those method, also no one really needing this and complaining is what prevented them (this might be your moment to shine up with a PR implementing it, why not?). Anyway, I really suck with trigonometry, but AFAIR, tan could be obtained with sin and cos someway that I don't remember. No idea about acos and asin.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @AlterLagos
Interesting to see that is issue exists but isn't taken care of as long as nobody seems annoyed but these missing methods, which makes sense.
I might try to have a look to develop a PR myself indeed, it could be fun!

Comment: Sure, `sin`, `atan` and `cos` are just [plain ruby](https://github.com/ruby/bigdecimal/blob/master/lib/bigdecimal/math.rb), no C involved, so it's achievable.